# How to decrease select option list for adding select option dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here from the following code I know how to add row dynamically in java script.
But I can not decrease the option list by adding options. It means that if I select country India and after adding another option without India options will only occur in the option list for second row. and the process is going as per selection.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
        function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

                var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

                newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
                //alert(newcell.childNodes);
                switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                    case "text":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                            break;
                    case "checkbox":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                            break;
                    case "select-one":
                            newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                            break;
                }
            }
        }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

    <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
        <TR>
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
            <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt"/></TD>
            <TD>
                <SELECT name="country">
                    <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
                </SELECT>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cj12LLop/

Comment: I can not remove the previous selected option from current option list by adding row.

Answer (score 0):

You want to delete the row (tr) from the table, where the checkbox in the row is activated?

Comment: no I just want to remove the select options list one by one as per selecting the previous option. e.g. If I choose first option "India" and after adding new row the generated select list does not contain india. It shows only Germany to Swtzrlnd.

Comment: Why don't  you use jquery or another js-framework? is it important to use only javascript without an js-framework? par example in jquery it is easy to create a solution for yout app..